# How can I fit in more links at the right without crowding only in one line by moving them slightly to the left?

Tags: html, css

So I want it to float to the right, but I want the text and one image (which I haven't turned to links yet) to be in one line.

HTML code:

```html
<html>
<title>Home - Welcome to Micro Skills!</title>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
<div id="header" class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="logo">
<h1><img src="microskills_logo.jpg" width="275" height="106" alt="Logo -  Micro Sills"></h1>
</div>
<div class="navBar">
<ul>
<b>
<li><img src="home_icon.jpg" width="256" height="256" alt="Home" class="home_icon"></li>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Events</li>
<li>Get Involved</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
</b>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<p>Welcome to the Community MicroSkills Development Centre website.

Since 1984, we have been serving communities in the Greater Toronto Area. As a non-profit, charitable organization, we strive to achieve excellence in our service delivery to women, newcomers to Canada, youth and other community members who trust us to support them in improving their economic and social well-being.
Community MicroSkills Development Centre is a multi-cultural, non-profit, community based organization committed to assisting the unemployed, with priority to women, racial minorities, youth and immigrants. Recognizing barriers that immigrants, racial minority, youth and women face in their efforts towards self-sufficiency, MicroSkills aims to enable them to participate more fully in Canadian society and assist them in acquiring the skills needed to achieve self-determination and economic, social and political equality.
Our programs are designed to assist the unemployed, with priority to women, racial minorities, youth and immigrants achieve career and personal goals. Clients can choose as many services as required to help them on their way to becoming self-reliant and economically self-sufficient.</p>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body{
width:100%;
margin:auto;    
}
.container{
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
}
.header{
    background-color:#900;
    width:100%;
    height:17%;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    text-decoration:none;

}
.logo{
    float:left;
}
.navBar{
    float:right;
    height: 10px;
}
li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:2%;
    padding-top:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    font-stretch:ultra-condensed;
    padding-right:0;

}
.content{
    padding-top:20%;
}
.home_icon{
    height:50px;
    width:50px; 
}
```

I want the same positioning, but I want to move the text and image in the "navBar" slightly to the left to fit everything in one line.

Comment: jsFiddle please.. :X

Comment: JSfiddle please. Or codepen

Comment: title tag should be in head tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `width` property to your `.navBar` CSS.

http://codepen.io/calebanth/pen/KrZBXo

```
.navBar {
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
    width: 30%;
}
```